# Gyro vs accelerometer for rotational acceleration

Tags: accelerometer, gyro

For the same price chip, which will be more accurate to measure rotational acceleration: a gyroscope, or an accelerometer 10cm away from the pivot point?

Comment: Do you want to integrate the rotational acceleration to compute the orientation, or just keep it as is?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Keep it as is. I would differentiate the orientation to get the rotational acceleration.

Comment: a gyroscope would give you an output in \$\frac{\text{rad}}{s}\$, you can differentiate it to get \$\frac{\text{rad}}{s^2}\$, is that right?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gyroscope will be more accurate, but is highly subjet to drift, which is the reason why they are often used with an accelerometer and even sometimes with a compass.

Accelerometer alone will be slow.

I would suggest you watch this conference : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k

Comment: So, the impression I'm getting is to use both and combine the data, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the best thing to do. Nowadays, you can find ship including compass, accelerometer and gyroscope for a price comparable to a gyroscope alone.